# Trouble running local WordPress in Google App Engine

Tags: php, python, wordpress, google-app-engine, python-imaging-library

Following [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress).

Installed MySQL, Python and Google App Engine PHP SDK on a Windows 8 PC. Perfect!

Created an app for WordPress, created database and user on localhost and edited WordPress config accordingly.

Started the app in the Google App Engine Launcher. Clicking Browse leads to blank page at `http://localhost:8080/`

Hmmm...

Checked logs, found

```
2013-11-26 17:56:18 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\python.exe', 
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', 
'--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=8080', '--admin_port=8000',
'C:\\Users\\CsillamVilag\\Documents\\development-appengine\\arcfestesmintak']" 
INFO     2013-11-26 17:56:19,805 devappserver2.py:660] 
Skipping SDK update check. 
WARNING  2013-11-26 17:56:19,813 api_server.py:331] 
Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module. 
INFO     2013-11-26 17:56:19,822 api_server.py:138] 
Starting API server at: http://localhost:53853 
INFO     2013-11-26 17:56:19,826 dispatcher.py:171] 
Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080 
INFO     2013-11-26 17:56:19,828 admin_server.py:117] 
Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000 
INFO     2013-11-26 17:56:21,828 module.py:617] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
```

Pretty certain the Python for Windows package I used included PIL. Not sure where to go from here...

If I go to `http://localhost:8080/wp-admin` though, I get

```
Warning: chdir(): Invalid argument (errno 22) in C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\php\setup.php on line 42

Warning: require(wordpress/wp-admin/wp-admin/install.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\php\setup.php on line 103

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'wordpress/wp-admin/wp-admin/install.php' (include_path='C:\Users\CsillamVilag\Documents\development-appengine\arcfestesmintak;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\php\sdk') in C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\php\setup.php on line 103
```

In the error returned at `http://localhost:8080/wp-admin/` I see `/wp-admin/wp-admin/install.php`

Obviously `install.php` cant be found. It is in `/wp-admin/` not in `/wp-admin/wp-admin/`
Not sure how to fix that.

Comment: The last line of your log output is a HTTP redirect from / to another page, is there anymore log output with more information, the output you have provided appears to have been interrupted.

Comment: The missing PIL library is normal, unless you are using the image processing features of AppEngine there is no need to install it.

Comment: Hmm... That's the end of the log file...

Comment: @IanGSY Ok, but how do I get WordPress to work? Getting a blank page...

Comment: I know nothing about PHP however this part of the error is probably the crux of your problem `Warning: require(wordpress/wp-admin/wp-admin/install.php): failed to open stream:`    it can't find `wordpress/wp-admin/wp-admin/install.php`.  the earlier `chdir` error will be part of the same problem.

Comment: I see /wp-admin/wp-admin/ - that's twice...of course it can't find the file...because in reality it should just be /wp-admin/...how do I go about fixing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Google App Engine doesn't support WordPress 3.7.1 (something that's not documented anywhere). Downgrading to WordPress 3.5.1 (the version mentioned in Google's instructions) made it work - `http://localhost:8080` was forwarded to WordPress Install page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a blank page, you'll want to check your errors

In your /wordpress/wp_config.php file set

define('WP_DEBUG', false);
@ini_set('display_errors',0);

to

define('WP_DEBUG', true);
@ini_set('display_errors',1);

and see what is output when you go to

```
http://localhost:8080
```

Comment: Makes sense, but didn't help. Still getting blank page.